# What to do if the standard error estimates for adaptive Lasso estimates are useless?

Tags: standard-error, lasso

This is more of an advisory question. I am researching the performance of the adaptive Lasso on multidimensional GARCH MIDAS data under regime switching and other confounders for my bachelors. I know that the Lasso estimates are biased but I thought for the adaptive lasso estimates:

> "This further encourages the use of an adaptive LASSO penalty, which leads to asymptotically unbiased estimates (see Zou 2006).".

At the moment I am working on the performance measures (PM) of my simulation study to quantify the results. For the PM I mainly worked along the works of Tim Morris and Ian White so far (futher suggestions are always welcome).

Well turns out that the model SE estimates are pretty much garbage and the EmpSE are much higher. Model selection works fine though. Are PM like CIs, Coverage, Relative % error in Model SE, etc.  that use SE even of concern in the Lasso case?

I still can look at the Bias, variance, test MSE/MAD, false positives/negatives and maybe I will find a couple more that are interesting but would you just drop the model SE estimates alltogether or try to do bootstrap. I dont really want to do bootstrap because that would also increase the computation time, which is already pretty high.

Comment: Take a look at Chapter 6 of [Statistical Learning with Sparsity](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/StatLearnSparsity/) about the issues concerning inference on predictors in LASSO. They are tricky, even in simple LASSO. Usually _predictive performance_ of the model is the main concern, which can be evaluated with train/test splits if you have a very large data set (as you presumably do, if computation time is already a problem). [This post](https://www.fharrell.com/post/split-val/) discusses train/test versus resampling.